# Showing some inequalities involving norms on smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $U \subset M$ open, $f : U \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and $Df_x : T_x M \to T_{f(x)} M$, $x \in M$. Let $\Lambda \subset M$  be a compact $f$-invariant set such that there exists  $\lambda < 1 < \mu$ and for every $x \in \Lambda$, there is a $(\lambda, \mu)$-splitting such that 
$T_x M = E^s_x \bigoplus E^u_x$ and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$ \| {Df^n_x}_{|E^s_x} \| \leq \lambda^n, \;\;  \|({Df_x}_{|E^u_x})^{-n} \| \leq \mu^{-n}.$$
(Such a set $\Lambda$ is called a hyperbolic set.)

I can't show show that for any Riemann metric on $U$ there exist $C > 0$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ such that for every $x \in \Lambda$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\| Df^n_x(v) \| \leq c \lambda^n \|v\|, \;\text{for every}\; v \in E^s_x,$$
$$\| Df^{-n}_x(w) \| \leq c \lambda^n \|w\|, \;\text{for every}\; w \in E^u_x.$$

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Look at unit tangent bundle $S_\Lambda M$ and use the continuity of the Riemannian metric to obtain uniform bounds on the whole $S_\Lambda M$ between the two norms (old and new). Notice that you don't need to use the fact that all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional space.